# Pandas Merge function creating incorrect data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

I am attempting to join two data frames together. However, when I use the Merge function in Pandas, in some cases it is creating rows that should not be present and are not accurate.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeAway Type': ['Sick', 'Vacation', 'Late'], 'Date': ['2022-03-09', '2022-03-09', '2022-03-15'], 'Hours Requested': [0.04, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Schedule Segment': ['Sick', 'VTO', 'Tardy'], 'Date': ['2022-03-09', '2022-03-09', '2022-03-15'], 'Duration': [2, 3, 1]})
merged = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['Date'])
print(merged)
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrafV.png)

As you can see from the image above, on the date where there is only 1 instance in each DF, everything works perfectly fine. However, on the dates where there are more than one in each DF, it is producing extra rows. It's almost as if it's saying "I don't know how to match this data so here's every single possible combination."

Desired Output:

[Desired output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rn7R.png)

This is just a subset of the data. The DF is quite large and there are a lot more instances of where this occurs with different values. Is there anything that can be done to stop this from happening?

Comment: I wish. That would make it easy for sure. Sadly, VTO can be matched up with a lot of different values. and same for vacation. and basically all the variables. I was hoping there would be a way to simple join them in the order they are in and avoid creating those extra rows.

Answer (score 0):

Update per comment in question to join on order of records by date:

```
df_o=df.assign(date_order=df.groupby('Date').cumcount())
df2_o=df2.assign(date_order=df2.groupby('Date').cumcount())

df_o.merge(df2_o, on=['Date','date_order'])
```

Output:

```
  TimeAway Type        Date  Hours Requested  date_order Schedule Segment  Duration
0          Sick  2022-03-09             0.04           0             Sick         2
1      Vacation  2022-03-09             3.00           1              VTO         3
2          Late  2022-03-15             5.00           0            Tardy         1
```

Create a psuedo key to join on order the by count in each day.

---

Try this:

```
df2['TimeAway Type'] = (df2['Schedule Segment'].map({'VTO':'Vacation', 
                                                    'Tardy':'Late',})
                                               .fillna(df2['Schedule Segment']))
merged = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['TimeAway Type', 'Date'])
merged
```

Output:

```
  TimeAway Type        Date  Hours Requested Schedule Segment  Duration
0          Sick  2022-03-09             0.04             Sick         2
1      Vacation  2022-03-09             3.00              VTO         3
2          Late  2022-03-15             5.00            Tardy         1
```

Comment: The issue is that in some cases, VTO might be matched with a different value not shown in this table. If I do that, it would exclude those values. The point behind joining them is so that the user can make comparisons. The values need to be more flexible. There are a lot of different ways the data could match up. This is only one instance out of lots.

Comment: @BrOtis See update... you can create a date_order (a column to join on denoting the order inwhich the records appear in each day).

Comment: So you're saying that I would need to go through the .map section of the code and outline every single possible combination of matches? that would be quite large. VTO could match up with Vations, Sick, Leave, lots of stuff. and other values do that same thing. So I'd need to create an instance of each possible paring in the .map part?

Comment: @BrOtis Yes.  That is the best way to ensure you are getting the proper match up.